# Why this @OneToOne bidirectional relationship gives me a null proxy when querying the owning entity?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, one-to-one, bidirectional

I'm using Hibernate 5.2.4.
These are the two entities that have a one-to-one bidirectional relationship:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="post")
public class Post {
    @Id
    @Column(name="id", nullable=false)
    private int id;

    @Column(name="text", nullable=false)
    private String text;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="post", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, optional=true)
    private PostDetails details;

    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name="post_details")
public class PostDetails implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, optional=false)
    @JoinColumn(name="post_id", nullable=false)
    private Post post;

    @Column(name="date", nullable=false)
    private Date date;
    ...
}
```

It's the most basic case of one-to-one bidirectional relationship. I think the only thing that deviates from the basic case is the fact that `PostDetails` uses the `Post` as its ID instead of having its own ID.

These are the tables:

[image]

This is my data:

[image]

And finnaly this is my query:

```
PostDetails pd = s.createQuery(
        "select pd"
        + " from PostDetails pd"
        + " join [fetch] pd.post p"
        + " where p.text like '%banana%'"
    , PostDetails.class)
    .setMaxResults(1)
    .getSingleResult();

System.out.println(pd.getDate());
System.out.println(pd.getPost().getText()); // Null pointer here even when "join fetch" is used
```

Why `pd.getPost()` gives me a `null`? No matter if I use or not `join fetch` I always get a `null`. By using `join fetch` the generated SQL queries for all columns of both tables but the `Post` proxy is still null. Using `EAGER` as fetch type doesn't solve either.

If I make this relationship unidirectional by removing the `PostDetails` from `Post` everything works fine. Why is that?

Here is the complete code for this example:

[Post.java](http://pastebin.com/6G6vuGSY)

[PostDetails.java](http://pastebin.com/dteaGyxU)

[Query](http://pastebin.com/Ds3rayz4)

[SQL script](http://pastebin.com/zMC0i5ah)

Comment: Conceptually it would make more sense to query for a Post. However can you post the generated SQL.

Comment: @AlanHay If you think of this SSCCE, yes. What I really want to query is PostDetails. I don't even need Post initialized. The problem is that if/when I do need the Post, instead of having a proxy that will trigger a query and give me it's attributes, I will get a null pointer. I added the entire code of the example.
Here is the [generated SQL](http://pastebin.com/aBVJNMKt)